# How to manually trigger a redirect to another page without changing the url address?

Tags: php

I am trying to make it so when a regular user enters a place they shouldn't be, then they should be redirected to the 404 page, but the url must remain the same, as if they have entered an invalid address, so there is no way to know by looking at the address bar that the user has stumbled upon an admin page.

Since the redirect shouldn't happen always it can't be done though .htaccess and currently allow_url_include is disabled and I've read that it's strongly recommended that it should remain that way so I can't use `include()` with an `exit`.

update1: `require()` and `require_once()` appear to work, but they still add a `/` at the end of the URL.

Comment: I cannot think of url that will be 404... every page, for ex. mysite.com/some_extra/not/existing will be looking for page and if not found will echo Page not found not 404...

Comment: `regular user enters a place they shouldn't be` how does the system decide that?

Comment: @Ejay `if(!current_user_can('update_core')){ redirect_code_goes_here }`

Answer (score 1):

You can try to use the `template_redirect` hook to check your conditions and then set the `wp_query->is_404` variable, like below:

```
function wpse202198_set_404(){
      global $post;
      global $wp_query;
      if( $post->ID == PAGE_ID_OF_PROTECTED_PAGE ){
           $wp_query->is_404 = true;
           return;
      }
}
add_action( 'template_redirect', 'wpse202198_set_404' );
```

Comment: Tried copying this (and replacing `PAGE_ID_OF_PROTECTED_PAGE` with the actual ID of course) at the beginning of the game without adding any other conditions and it doesn't trigger at all.

Comment: Not sure I understand what you mean by `at the beginning of the game` but I guess I should have mentioned that this should go in your theme `functions.php` file

Comment: I meant "page". I see no difference between putting this at the beginning of the page, after the header has been called, or in functions.php

Comment: @Nadroev a template redirect hook will never trigger in a template file, because it runs before the template is loaded. that's why it must go in functions.php, or a plugin.